# Need help getting High and low values and their corresponding dates from an SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to use this but it just times out and keeps loading forever. I'm trying to get a slug's high, low, and corresponding date for the high and low

```
SELECT usd,date,slug,datediff(CURDATE(), date) as datediff FROM historical h 
inner join(
SELECT MIN(usd + 0) as low FROM historical GROUP BY slug
)i 
inner join(
SELECT MAX(usd + 0) as high FROM historical GROUP BY slug
)j 
WHERE h.usd = i.low OR h.usd = j.high
```

sample data:

```
slug    |   usd     |    date .     
------------------------------------        
gold    |   435    |  01-05-2015 . 
gold    |   5      |  01-12-2015 . 
gold    |   251    |  01-06-2015 . 
gold    |   353    |  01-07-2015 . 
silver  |   5      |  01-08-2015 . 
silver  |   4      |  01-09-2015 . 
silver  |   78     |  01-15-2015 . 
silver  |   100    |  01-25-2015 .
```

what I want back:

```
slug     |  high   |    highdate   |   low    |  lowdate 
------------------------------------------------------------
gold     |  435   |   01-05-2015  |   5     |  01-12-2015
silver   |  100   |   01-25-2015  |   4     |  01-09-2015
```

When I try to use this for just the low values, it works 100% perfectly

```
SELECT usd,btc,date,slug,datediff(CURDATE(), date) as datediff FROM historical h 
inner join(
    SELECT MIN(usd + 0) as low FROM historical GROUP BY slug
)i 
WHERE h.usd = i.low
```

Comment: Is USD really stored as a string?

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes, I just created the database, I know I have to change it but that's besides the point for now lol

Comment: It is the point. And store dates as dates

Comment: I have the dates stored as dates, I just put them in a different format for the example

Comment: How are we supposed to guess that, or that '$' is not part of the input? We can only go on the information provided. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
select h.slug,
       min(case when replace(usd, '$', '') + 0 = min_usd then usd end) as min_usd,
       min(case when replace(usd, '$', '') + 0 = min_usd then usd end) as min_date,
       max(case when replace(usd, '$', '') + 0 = max_usd then usd end) as max_usd,
       min(case when replace(usd, '$', '') + 0 = max_usd then usd end) as max_date
from historical h join
     (select slug, min(replace(usd, '$', '') + 0) as min_usd,
             max(replace(usd, '$', '') + 0) as max_usd
      from historical 
      group by slug
     ) s
     on h.slug = s.slug
group by h.slug;
```

The calculation for the `min()` and `max()` is rather tricky, because you are storing the value as a string.  I strongly recommend that you store the value as a decimal/numeric type.  That is appropriate for currencies.

EDIT:

The question changed slightly.  The appropriate query seems to be:

```
select h.slug,
       min(case when usd + 0 = min_usd then usd end) as min_usd,
       min(case when usd + 0 = min_usd then usd end) as min_date,
       max(case when usd + 0 = max_usd then usd end) as max_usd,
       min(case when usd + 0 = max_usd then usd end) as max_date
from historical h join
     (select slug, min(usd + 0) as min_usd,
             max(usd + 0) as max_usd
      from historical 
      group by slug
     ) s
     on h.slug = s.slug
group by h.slug;
```

All the `+ 0`s are only needed if `usd` is stored as a string.  Otherwise numeric comparisons are fine.

Comment: Thanks, I actually don't have the $ signs stored in there but I will try your code without the part that removes them

Comment: I tried this: select slug,
       min(case when usd + 0 = min_usd then usd end) as min_usd,
       min(case when usd + 0 = min_usd then usd end) as min_date,
       max(case when usd + 0 = max_usd then usd end) as max_usd,
       min(case when usd + 0 = max_usd then usd end) as max_date
from historical h join
     (select slug, min(usd + 0) as min_usd,
             max(usd + 0) as max_usd
      from historical 
      group by slug
     ) s
     on h.slug = s.slug
group by slug;

and got: #1052 - Column 'slug' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: @noobiedev: Replace the first `slug` (right after `select`) with `h.slug`.